# forwarding message with telegram bot just working with channels that bot in them

Tags: php, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I create a bot on webhook.
api for `forwardMessage` works before but not working now.
is there any problem in telegram api?

here is my code

```
<?php

$website="https://api.telegram.org/bot".$botToken;

$params=[
    'chat_id' => "-1001109418",
    'from_chat_id'=>'-1001084672759',
    'message_id' => '24228',
];
$ch = curl_init($website . '/forwardMessage');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ($params));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);


curl_close($ch);



?>
```

any way to forward from other channels?

Answer (score 0):

`chat_id` and `from_chat_id` are correct?
or try GET

```
  $ch = curl_init( $website.'/forwardMessage'.http_build_query( $params ) );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
  curl_exec( $ch );

  curl_close( $ch );
```

Comment: i think that code not working because bot was not a member of channel.is there any way to forward from other channels?when i forwarded from channel that bot is a member of my code is true..